# Assigning CSS value via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to apply CSS using Javascript.
I assigned the width of #test-div to var 'wid' and then assign the same the value to the height of #test-div. 
However, value of height is not changing.

```js
var wid = document.getElementById("test-div").style.width
document.getElementById("test-div").style.height = wid
```

```css
#test-div {
  width: 320px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="test-div">
  <img src="https://u01.appmifile.com/images/2017/10/27/467720b2-5023-4460-864a-cd2dde58ee3b.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: you want to apply the height of the image by using ratio of 16:9?

Comment: Try `document.getElementById("test-div").height = wid` or `document.getElementById("test-div").style.height = wid + "px"`

Comment: @KuldipKoradia yes, I actually want to apply this concept on iFrame

Comment: use this var wid = document.getElementById("test-div").offsetWidth;

Comment: [https://jsfiddle.net/nt27yodg/3/](https://jsfiddle.net/nt27yodg/3/)

Comment: posted my answer please review it once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use this code, I hope this will work for you.

```js
var wid = document.getElementById("test-div").offsetWidth;
var hei = (wid) * 9 / 16;
document.getElementById("test-div").style.height = hei+'px';
```

```css
#test-div {
  width: 400px;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="test-div">
  <img src="https://u01.appmifile.com/images/2017/10/27/467720b2-5023-4460-864a-cd2dde58ee3b.jpg">
</div>
```

this is the demo by using `max-width` instead of `width`.

```js
var wid = document.getElementById("test-div").offsetWidth;
var hei = (wid) * 9 / 16;
document.getElementById("test-div").style.height = hei+'px';
```

```css
#test-div {
  max-width: 400px;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="test-div">
  <img src="https://u01.appmifile.com/images/2017/10/27/467720b2-5023-4460-864a-cd2dde58ee3b.jpg">
</div>
```

Thank You...

Comment: What if I had "max-width: 400px;" instead of "width: 400px;" for #test-div? offsetWidth returns undefined in that case

Comment: no its works properly for that case also. I have checked it for the max-width: 400px;

Comment: I have update my ans by using max-width instead of width.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed 'px', try the following:-

```
var wid = document.getElementById("test-div").style.width
document.getElementById("test-div").style.height = `${wid}px`;
```